# Random slideshow using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

*Using JavaScript, implement an image slideshow viewer with the following requirements:

- Name the HTML page as imageSlideShow.html and the corresponding JavaScript as 
  imageSlideShow.js
- The slideshow should consist of 5 different images.
- Upon a click of a button, a different photo selected at random must be displayed on the 
  webpage.

I have part of the script, but i cant figure out how to actually create a slideshow with a random button.

This is what I have for javascript:

```
var image1=New Image()
image1.src="image1.jpg"

var image2=New Image()
image1.src="image2.jpg"

var image3=New Image()
image1.src="image3.jpg"

var image4=New Image()
image1.src="image4.jpg"

var image5=New Image()
image1.src="image5.jpg"
```

and this is what the html part looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/Javascript" src="imageSlideShow.js"></script>
        <img src="image1.jpg" name="slide1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" value="random" onclick="slideshow()" >Random Image</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The images are not "random", you hard-code them. What is exactly the problem? Do you need to know how to create an array? (Big Hint...)

Comment: i can create an array, but what code would i use to connect the button to the function that would be name"slideshow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a slideshow, it's just an image and you're changing the source randomly every time a button is clicked (calling a JavaScript function).

My suggestion is to use JavaScript to generate a random number between 1 and 5. Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="" id="image">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function buttonClicked() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
    document.getElementById("image").src="image"+randomNumber+".jpg";
}
```

`Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1)` generates a random number from 1 to 5. From here, `document.getElementById` uses `randomNumber` to randomly generate part of the source URL of the element. What you end up getting is an image source which is dependent on the number between 1 and 5 that you randomly generated.

Comment: so if i used the method, how would the images that i want to use be connected to the fuction?

Comment: They are connected because the image source is randomly generated and matches up with the file names that you provided. `document.getElementById("image").src="image"+randomNumber+".jpg";` will produce results such as "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", etc. These are the image names that you provided in your original post.

Comment: ok, well using that method, it still didn't work. clicking the button didnt change the picture at all.

Comment: Can you post all of the code that you tried? Saying that it "doesn't work" doesn't help.

Comment: var image1=New Image()

 image1.src="image1.jpg"
 
var image2=New Image()

 image2.src="image2.jpg"
 
var image3=New Image()

 image3.src="image3.jpg"
 
var image4=New Image()

 image4.src="image4.jpg"

var image5=New Image()

 image5.src="image5.jpg"
 


function buttonClicked()
{
 var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
 document.GetElementById("image").src="image" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
}

Comment: the java console is telling me that there was an unexpected syntax error with the var image1

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the method. You don't need to define each image as a JavaScript variable. Instead, all need is for the images to be in the same directory as your HTML file. Make sure that you have `id=image` in your HTML `<img>` tag. That might be the problem. Also, you can try alerting the value of `document.getElementById("image").src` to see if you are getting the expected results.

Comment: ok, i got it, i didnt realize that you didnt need to have the images defined in the javascript file. So thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. If I fully resolved your issue, please mark this answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can randomize your images using this:

```
   function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };

var imgs ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg","image5.jpg"];

imgs = shuffle(imgs);

var pos = 0;

slideshow(){
   image1.src=imgs[pos];
   pos = (pos+1)%imgs.length;
}
```

this is the basic idea, you can customize this script to your needs.